# How to reload a particular div in which input tag is there on press of enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have a search box at the top of page that makes an ajax call when a user hits the adjacent button. I am trying to update the input tag so that when a user hit the 'enter' key, the appropriate JavaScript takes place without reloading the page. without using form

```
$('#Searchbar').bind("enterkey", function (e) {
    $("#Searchbar").load('Search(1);');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#Searchbar').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 10 || event.keyCode === 13) {        
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to load the result in the same div in which #searchbar is there.

Comment: can you show the content of the search function.

Comment: you can look at ajax

Comment: *"makes an ajax call when a user hits the adjacent button"* - where is the code for this? Can't you just invoke that function when enter key is pressed? BTW what does this has to do with jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#Searchbar').on("enterkey", function(e) {
  //
  search('whatever your search string might be', function(result) {
   // get the result and put in the resultcontainer
    $('.resultContainer').html(result);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#Searchbar').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 10 || event.keyCode === 13) {
    $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function search(data, callback) {
  //Do an ajax call and call the callback on succes
  //Check for proper syntax in jquery documentation
  $.post({
    'data': data,
    'url': your search url,
    success: function(result) {
      callback(result);
    }
  });
}
```